# is it possible to add if Condition to mysql insert query"

Tags: php, sql, insert

i use code that inserts data into DB from array in loop.

```
foreach ($sumdrinks1 as $key => $value)    // insert each part of array into DB
{
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (liq_sum, liq_name, bartender)
VALUES ('$value','$key','$id'))";
}
```

becuse i dont need the results that $value = 0, i run another query to delete them from the DB

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM table WHERE liq_sum = 0");
```

is there are way to add  if Condition in the insert query instead of insert them and delting them?
I tried somethink like:

```
 ("INSERT INTO table (liq_sum, liq_name, bartender) 
 VALUES ('$value','$key','$id') where '$value' > 0)";
```

didn't work :(

thank you.

Comment: Just add `if ($value > 0)` inside your loop

Comment: Please try to make your question clearly. Take some interest in your format. i.e. Capitalization, etc,.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it in php

```
    foreach ($sumdrinks1 as $key => $value)    // insert each part of array into DB
    {
     if($value>0)
     mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (liq_sum, liq_name, bartender) VALUES     ('$value','$key','$id')");
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the value using `if` statement:

```
foreach ($sumdrinks1 as $key => $value)  
{
   if ($value > 0) {
      ... // do insert
   }
}
```

**Note that:** `mysql_` extensions are deprecated, and your code this way is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this condition in php code itself.

```
foreach ($sumdrinks1 as $key => $value)    // insert each part of array into DB

{
    if($value > 0) {
         mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (liq_sum, liq_name, bartender) VALUES ('$value','$key','$id'))";

    }

}
```